# Kubuntu Alt+F2 broken after 20.04 upgrade

Tags: kubuntu, krunner

After upgrade from Kubuntu 19.10 to 20.04, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> does nothing. If I run runner from CLI then I have the launcher pop up.

Comment: What happens with `Alt+Spacebar`?

Comment: On a clean install of Kubuntu 20.04, `Alt+F2` should be an alternative. Maybe it's been unset? If so, just set it again: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtGYM.png

Comment: Alt+Space do nothing also. And both are in Global keybinding

Answer (score 5):

Broken here after 19.10 to 20.04 upgrade.

Perhaps there is a problem with some automatic upgrade process.

Running the following fixed it for me:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/kconf_update_bin/krunnerglobalshortcuts
```

Sources:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1781054

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=413368

Answer (score 3):

I've solved the issue. Seems like new KDE has two ways for 'run' menu actually 'Command run' and Krunner. So the first one probably introduced recently and stole keybinding from Krunner! If you change it to Krunner then it will work as before (just look for run Krunner keybindings)